# Line chart color by value trend

Tags: c#, .net, mschart

Is it possible to create a line chart by mschart, which's part of a line color is different by its trend? I mean, part of the line, where values are ascending, are different, than the part, where aelues are ascending, and different, where equal.

Answer (score 0):

There is some VBA code for it at peltier forums (Conditional formatting of lines in line chart):

http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/conditional-formatting-of-lines-in-an-excel-line-chart-using-vba/

I'm not aware of an automatic way of doing it.